# R: quantmod, chartseries and PDF

Tags: r, png, quantmod

What is the best way to graph 8 charts at once using quantmod?

Here are some options:

1. collate all 8 charts in memory, then combine into a 8.5" x 11" pdf

2. save each chart as a png, then combine into a pdf

I would prefer option #1 to #2.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quantmod)
s = c("AAL","DAL","UAL","LUV","FDX","ALK","JBLU","HA")

# example of charts to graph
getSymbols("AAL", src="yahoo")
chartSeries(AAL, type="line",subset='last 60 months',
  TA="addSMA(200,col='orange');addSMA(65,col='red')")
getSymbols("DAL", src="yahoo")
chartSeries(DAL, type="line",subset='last 60 months',
  TA="addSMA(200,col='orange');addSMA(65,col='red')")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(quantmod)
s = c("AAL","DAL","UAL","LUV","FDX","ALK","JBLU","HA")

symbols <- list (getSymbols(s, source = "yahoo"))

pdf(file = "charts.pdf")
par(mfrow = c( 8, 1 ) )
chartSeries(AAL, type="line",subset='last 60 months', TA="addSMA(200,col='orange');addSMA(65,col='red')")
chartSeries(DAL, type="line",subset='last 60 months', TA="addSMA(200,col='orange');addSMA(65,col='red')")
chartSeries(UAL, type="line",subset='last 60 months', TA="addSMA(200,col='orange');addSMA(65,col='red')")
chartSeries(LUV, type="line",subset='last 60 months', TA="addSMA(200,col='orange');addSMA(65,col='red')")
chartSeries(FDX, type="line",subset='last 60 months', TA="addSMA(200,col='orange');addSMA(65,col='red')")
chartSeries(ALK, type="line",subset='last 60 months', TA="addSMA(200,col='orange');addSMA(65,col='red')")
chartSeries(JBLU, type="line",subset='last 60 months', TA="addSMA(200,col='orange');addSMA(65,col='red')")
chartSeries(HA, type="line",subset='last 60 months', TA="addSMA(200,col='orange');addSMA(65,col='red')")
dev.off()
```

**screenshots of the pdf**

Completely zoomed out

[image]

a bit closer

[image]

### UPDATE

You can use `chart_Series()`, shich respects the settings in `par()`. But I am not getting the arguments right, so the charts do not look as nice as with `chartSeries`.

```
pdf(file = "charts.pdf")
par(mfrow = c( 4, 2 ) )
chart_Series(AAL)
chart_Series(DAL)
chart_Series(UAL)
chart_Series(LUV)
chart_Series(FDX)
chart_Series(ALK)
chart_Series(JBLU)
chart_Series(HA)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: possible improvement: use a separate environment and `eapply()`  but i could not get this to work properly.

Comment: Can you show the output of doing this with 8 symbols at the same time? and attach a PNG to your answer?

Comment: can you do a 4,2 or 3,3 so it fits on one sheet?  A large column is extremely hard to read.

Comment: Note that there is a lot of redundant information in the last pdf. eg. I can see the year information twice on the x-axis.

Comment: @AG1 I;m not very familiar with the function `chart_Series`. A lot can (probably) be adjusted using the right arguments.